# Is there a way to remove the "Python" title from the Win10Toast Notification

Tags: python, notifications

The title says it all, I am trying to use the Win10Toast Notification System but it always shows the Python label on the side of the icon[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `show_toast()` ?

If so, you can use it to change the title and the icon:

```
show_toast(title="", message="", icon_path="");
```

Comment: its not the title but the source of the notification e.g. python is the source

Comment: In that case, it is probably the source that it's running it. I guess duplicating the `python.exe`, renaming it, making it the preferred program to run the script could do the trick?

Comment: exactly its the execution source . the above tip may work assuming the filename is considered as source

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh now I understand, and thanks to Zain UI Abidin too, I am running the program throught a python script, but on the final project I will turn it into an exe, so it should get it's name. Thank you all

Comment: I've just tried to apply this (duplicate `python.exe`, rename, run with this dummy) but it still showed `Python`. It's possible this is actually hardcoded into the library. May I suggest `plyer.notification` instead? These will also stay in the action menu.